# How can I sync WordPress plugin settings between environments?

Tags: plugins, git, deployment, sync

I currently:

- Have identical environments for development ([vagrant](https://www.vagrantup.com/)) and production ([elastic beanstalk](http://aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/)).
- Use `git push` to deploy code from the development to the production environment.
- Create posts and pages using the production environment's WordPress.
- Import the production database into the development database to stay in sync.

---

While I know this strategy works, I feel lost when thinking about how to best manage the installation, activation and — most importantly — synchronization of WordPress' Plugins.

Installing plugins makes sense... Download. Commit. Deploy. And all environments will have the plugin available.

Activating and synchronizing plugin settings isn't as clear...  **Do I need to manually activate and setup each plugin on all environments, or can that be synced between them?**

I know each plugin can have unique way of storing data, but I would think with both file and database synchronization everything would match up. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reliable two–way sync is simply not something that have happened in WordPress.

The typical way is in line with what you are doing — pulling a copy of production database into development environment. Note that this is commonly the *one* direction it goes. It's much more problematic to try sync development back to production.

As far as plugin configuration specifically is concerned:

1. Call it good enough and treat production as authoritative state
2. Have codified install/update procedures, which dictate desired state of plugin options
3. Override plugins' options storage and/or internal hooks

The practical choice to go with would depend on specific plugins used and how complicated the state of their settings to be captured and/or reproduced is.

Comment: Thank you Rarst for your detailed response. Would you mind elaborating on the third suggestion you listed? I'm not quite sure what you meant by that.

Comment: Plugin settings are typically stored in options and/or pass through plugin's own filters. In many cases you can effectively override and hardcode that data using filters and ignoring the state captured in database.